# Free Email Server with Pickup Directory Like IIS SMTP server?

Tags: iis-6, smtp, windows-server-2003

Is there a free email server that will run on Windows 2003 server with a Pickup direcotry like the built in SMTP server for IIS? I have an application that dumps mail into a pickup direcotry and the IIS SMTP server queues and distributes the mail. I need something that does the smae thing, but also functions as a pop3 and smtp server. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Server 2003 you say? You want something that works like the SMTP server in IIS you say?

Why not use the SMTP server in IIS then? Why find something like it when you can use the one that's already available? If you need a POP server as well, you can install the Windows Server 2003 POP server component. Neither one requires any additional licensing.

Comment: I never knew there was a pop server for 2003. Nice! Thanks

Comment: Glad to help...